# Is there an way to get api gateway apikey value in a step function?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have an Express Step Function which is invoking a GET on my API Gateway via `arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke` and the task that looks like the following;

```
{
  "ApiEndpoint.$": "States.Format('{}.execute-api.{}.amazonaws.com',$.ApiID,$.Region)",
  "Method": "GET",
  "Headers": {
      "x-api-key.$": "$.ApiKey"
   },
  "Stage.$": "$.Environment",
  "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE",
  "Path.$": "States.Format('/getOrders/{}',$.CustomerID)"
}
```

My issue is that the method I need to invoke is secured with an APIKey.  So I have few thoughts (ordered by preference).

1. Is there a way to invoke this resource from the step function without the apikey header since I'm in my account?  Some type of resource policy?
2. Is there a way to get the value of an APIKey from some type of "get api details" step function task?
3. My API have 5 resource (all part of the same stage) secured by a single apikey.   Is there a way to secure the `getOrders` resource by a second apikeys (and only allow that apikey access to this resource)?

I'd rather not go to Lambda for this, if possible.

Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to do options 1, 2 or 3, so I went the route of putting the apikey in Secret Manager and then getting the secret out via the StepFunction get secret value task.  It works but it I would love to find a way to do option #3